# Load json into javascript

Tags: javascript, json

So I have a json html link that like below

```
www.pretendJsonLink.com/getData
```

and the data i receive is below:

```
{"Items":[{"date":1498850140373,"displayId":"003","sentId":"121213",
"customer":"ME"}, {"date":1452870140571,"displayId":"007","sentId":"152713",
"customer":"YOU"}],"Count":2,"ScannedCount":2}
```

I need to load this into a js file  so i can then call them as needed in a html file in an id="" tag

Like Items.date and Items.customer or something like it

Any help would be great and I understand that this should be a simple task, but i can also forward my search history as well :) i have been looking for solutions that work, but just cant seem to find anything that fits my needs

Comment: JSON.parse https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: What does your code look like? Are you using an `XMLHttpRequest` (aka AJAX)? If so why not set a variable in the callback and then do stuff with it?

Comment: Can you explain this part of your question a bit more, "the data i receive is below"? How are you receiving it? What is the code that you currently have to receive it?

Comment: i'm pretty much at the beginning, nothing code wise for actually parsing out the json data from the link.

Answer (score 1):

Use `JSON.parse()` function. Here is the link to [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Answer (score -1):

You can use [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) . I found a [gist](https://gist.github.com/MacKentoch/c10bc012f9c75c7c2c61) that gives a good example and included it (simplified), below:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', 'www.pretendJsonLink.com/getData');

req.onload = function() {
    if (req.status == 200) {
      // do what you want, here, with the req.response
      // take a look at the object that gets returned, you may need
      // to call JSON.parse(), etc.
      console.log('success', req.response);
    } else {
      console.log('error', req.statusText);
    }
};

// Handle network errors
req.onerror = function() {
    console.log("Network Error");
};

// Make the request
req.send();
```